# How can I run John Walker's ent program effectively on some data streams?

Tags: windows, cryptography

So the original ent program can be found [here.](https://www.fourmilab.ch/random/) The website doesn't give me a sufficient explanation, so I ask, how can I use this program *effectively* on Windows?

Comment: I'm sorry, but questions about using specific (cryptographic) tools are off-topic here on [crypto.se]. However, it should work for [su] which is why I have migrated it there.

Comment: What do mean by *"use this program effectively on Windows?"*